# Como verificar qual numero mais se aproxima a de outro em c?

Tags: c

Tenho umas 6 variáveis com inteiros, e tenho que descobrir qual delas mais se aproxima de um numero especifico, teria alguma maneira de fazer essa aproximação em c?

Comment: Basicamente você vai procurar quem tem a menor diferença absoluta. Você deveria mostrar o que tentou fazer. Caso não saiba nada de programação, ai este site não é adequado para sua dúvida.

Comment: Sim, é possível fazer isso tranquilamente. Não só em C, mas em todas as linguagens de programação que já trabalhei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isto é você tentar encontrar o menor valor absoluto (basicamente a menor diferença).

Supondo que você tem um número 100, e você tem 6 variáveis como ditas.
`Números 10, 20, 30, 50, 90, 105`.

Um cálculo simples é você pegar e fazer
`100 - 10 = 90`
`100 - 20 = 80`
`100 - 30 = 70`
`100 - 50 = 50`
`100 - 90 = 10`
`100 - 105 = -5`

Podemos ver que o que mais se aproxima seria o `-5`, mas por quê? Por conta do `-`? Não, porque devemos também fazer o módulo caso é um número negativo, assim ficando `5`.
Falando na forma de programação, você deve pegar o resultado da primeira equação e colocar em uma variável chamada `menor` por exemplo, e assim você irá comparar o resultado da próxima equação, se for `menor` que a primeira, você reatribui o valor na variável `menor`.
Lembrando, sempre colocar de forma `positiva`(módulo) os valores.